# Disable Screensaver While Using Hulu Desktop

Tags: screensaver

There is a file in your home folder that allows you to configure some settings for Hulu Desktop: `~/.huludesktop`. It has an option for scripts to run to dis/en-able the screensaver.

I would like to write a script to be called by Hulu while watching video. It seems that in Ubuntu 10.04 the gconftool settings `idle_activation_enabled` & `idle_activation_enabled` no longer inhibit the gnome-screensaver or monitor sleep.

These are the commands I tried to use:

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled --type bool TRUE
gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-powermanager/idle_activation_enabled --type bool TRUE
```

I have also found `gnome-screensaver-command` with the `--inhibit` option, but that blocks while active which means that my suspend script would be hard to fit into the two `.huludesktop` options (`suspend_script` & `resume_script`)

I would prefer not to use Caffine as this is under Ubuntu NBR and top panel space is valuable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat ~/bin/hulu-suspend
#!/bin/sh
# wrapper for gnome-screensaver-command utility to inhibit and 
# refrain from inhibiting screensaver. comments and robustness
# are sacrificed for simplicity

case $0 in
    *suspend*) 
        gnome-screensaver-command --application-name Hulu \
            --reason "watchin stuffs" --inhibit & 
        gnome-screensaver-command --query ;;
    *resume*) 
        killall gnome-screensaver-command;
        gnome-screensaver-command --query ;;
    *) echo "usage $0: read the script $0"; exit 1;;
esac
$ chmod +x ~/bin/hulu-suspend
$ ln ~/bin/hulu-suspend ~/bin/hulu-resume
$ hulu-suspend
The screensaver is being inhibited by:
Application="Hulu"; Since="2010-09-30T03:30:15.169875Z"; 
    Reason="watchin stuffs";
$ ln ~/bin/hulu-suspend ~/bin/hulu-resume
$ ~/bin/hulu-resume
The screensaver is not inhibited
```

It's been tested; it claims to work. Enjoy.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't even think about backgrounding the blocking command. I'll try this tonight and accept it if it works.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work from the .huludesktop file. I think that it needs a `DISPLAY=:0` ENV variable or else the gnome-screensaver-command errors: `** Message: Failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon: /bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.`

Comment: adding this line above the case statement causes the script to work for me in 10.04. `export DISPLAY=:0;`

Answer (score 2):

FYI, [Caffeine 2.2](https://launchpad.net/caffeine) now has an option to hide the tray icon:

[image]

To open the preferences again once the icon is hidden, run `caffeine -p` from
the command line or *System -> Preferences -> Caffeine Preferences*.